# NginX access configuration

Tags: ubuntu, web, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using ubuntu x64 server with nginx as webserver.

In my company, we configured intranet (local) dns server so that, when you enter **domain1.com**, it goes directly into defined LAN ip adress.

We need global access for domain2.com, which located in same server. When we open global access for **domain2.com**, occurred following problem:

As you know, anyone can detect ip adress of domain2.com (our server).

The problem is, when you access directly using server's global ip adress, server opens automatically **domain1.com** which must be restricted for global access. Here is nginx config of **domain1.com**:

```
server
{
set $host_path "/var/www/domain1";

server_name domain1.com;

root $host_path;
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

client_max_body_size 2000M;
client_body_buffer_size 1024k;

listen       80;

    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html;

access_log  /var/access_log;
error_log /var/error_log;

location ~ /(protected|framework|nbproject) {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }


}
```

How to make domain1.com only for LAN (restrict global access)?

Answer (score 0):

If nginx is serving a request that is missing hostname and none of the virtual servers has `default_server` parameter in their `listen` directive, it uses the first virtual server that it finds. In your case it is domain1.com. What you should do is to change the `listen` directive of **domain2.com** to:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

This way when someone uses your IP address without a hostname, they will be served domain2.com content.

If you want to strictly require a hostname and return 404 to requests that do not specify it, you can make a new server clause:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 404;
}
```

There is also another possible solution: if I understood correctly, your server has two IPs: internal and external. If this is true, you can change `listen` directive of **domain1.com** config to `listen 10.1.0.1:80;` where `10.1.0.1` is your internal IP address. This way domain1.com will only be reachable from your LAN.